# Get current HTML of rendered page using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, dom

I'm strugling to get the rendered html code in selenium of a facebook app. After login I go to the app page and use `time.sleep(20)` to wait for it to fully render.

I have already tried 3 solutions none of witch works:

```
self.driver.page_source # This one returns source code
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*').get_attribute('outerHTML')
self.driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML")
```

I'm using the google chrome driver and python3. Just to be clear.

EDIT 1 :

I wasn't clear about what don't work means. Each one of the above returns a different thing from what is presented when I hit "Inspect Element"

Comment: how do these three solutions not work? they return `None`, and error, ... ?

Comment: Scrapping [_Facebook_](https://www.facebook.com/) is against the [_ToS_](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms) and you are liable to be questioned and may even land up in [_Facebook Jail_](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=804287426255468). Use _Facebook API_ instead.

Comment: @OmarEinea They work but what they return is different from when I hit "Inspect Element"

Comment: @DebanjanB Thank you for that. I didn't know that. It's just for academic purposes

Comment: In what way does the returned string (for your third attempt) differ from what you see in inspect element?

Comment: @Alohci The third attempt returns the exact same thing of the second one. I'm not sure but it is like some elements are missing and I don't know why.

Comment: Sure. *Which* elements are missing? That may help us explain why you are getting the difference,

Answer (score 5):

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

...and don't use time.sleep(). Use a WebdriverWait and wait for a unique element on the page to load.

Comment: My question wasn't clear. Any way I edited it to clarify the problem. I've also tried your solution `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").get_attribute('outerHTML')` and it doesn't work. It just returns `body` instead of `html`. About `WebdriverWait`: can you explain it? –

Comment: There are plenty of resources on how and why to use WebdriverWait that I won't get into here, but I suggest you try it, you will like it.

I am not sure precisely which HTML you want, but try replacing "outerHTML" with "innerHTML" and let me know if that gets you anywhere.

Comment: @HelpNeeded101 I'd recommend `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html").get_attribute('outerHTML')` to get the full source rather than just the `body`.